How to generate compiler warning when using a C# enum's ToString method
We have some code which names infrastructure constructs based on a few criteria, including the environment name. Here's a simplified example:
enum AppEnvironment
{
    Dev,
    Staging,
    Production
}

static class AppEnvironmentExtensions
{
    static string AsString(this AppEnvironment env) => env switch
    {
        AppEnvironment.Dev => "dev",
        AppEnvironment.Staging => "stage",
        AppEnvironment.Production => "prod",
        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid environment")
    };
}

void BuildConstruct(string appName, AppEnvironment env)
{
    string constructName = $"{env}-{appName}"; // ← mistake

    // do infra stuff
}

The problem in this case is that it's too easy to accidentally let the underlying enum's ToString method get called during string interpolation when the actual requirement is to resolve the enum member to a different string (in this case, our AsString method). This can result in breakage that is very hard to track down. I know string constants wouldn't have this problem, but those wouldn't be ideal for other reasons.
A design-time solution would be to show a compiler warning when the code tries to use this enum's ToString method. Now it becomes an explicit decision for the developer to either use a different method or leave a #pragma warning disable statement to allow it. It would need to be smart enough to know when ToString is being called indirectly, such as in string interpolation or String.Format.
Is this something that would be simple to implement in a Roslyn analyzer?

Why not just override ToString instead of adding a new method. That way, devs can use the method they expect (as you can find ToString everywhere), and you have avoided them calling the default version.

C# enums do not allow method overrides. Even if they did, I think that would break JSON deserialization when resolving a string to an enum member.

Ooh, good point, I'd forgotten about that!

I have a problem with the concept of "accidents". If I tell my team that from now on, if they want to use the X member as a "name" or whatever, then "use this (static) fuction", and that's the end of it. I have "name getters" for small spaces vs bigger, last first vs first last, and so forth. If I find a reference to a "critical" property without the appropriate (trackable) setter or getter, I know what's what and who's responsible. (So, from a "compiler" POV, don't use member X without function Y (or Z).

@GerrySchmitz I don't think I quite understand what you're saying. Are you suggesting that the answer to preventing a base object method that gets called implicitly all over the place is to just tell people not to use it?

@Jacob Stamm "All over the place"? You identified string substitution and a "compiler". That is one context where I would say you use a "function" with "AppEnvironment" instead of the actual element. i.e. if a reference to AppEnvironment is directly imbedded in curlies and not with said function, it's an error. How hard is it to "scan" for that. I just "iterate" all my files a few times (with code) until all the "patterns" fall out.

@GerrySchmitz If the "scan" process you're describing is done with code, then that's exactly what an analyzer does, in which case we're saying the same thing. But if you're describing a manual process, i.e. "just be careful", then I can't consider that a valid solution. Also, "all over the place" is an apt description, since ToString is what's being called for interpolation, concatenation, casting, and logging methods, all of which are quite common and thus places where this mistake could easily be made.

If using simple ToString() which as you mentioned can be used implicitly in many many places can lead to a "breakage" then I would seriously reconsider this design choice instead of adding analyzer.

@Jacon Stamm The "scan" was suggested as a way to "scope" the situation. If it was a "data base", I could use BI. (Source files are just long strings; never "parsed" a text file before?) You say "all over the place" and we're talking an "enum". As some have suggested, if you don't know when it's being used as a string and when not, you may have "design" issues. (I constantly "refactor". It's part of the job).

ArchUnitNET can help find similar errors during tests. However, compiler warnings using the analyzer, of course, more convenient.

You could try something like this:
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using System.Collections.Immutable;
using System.Linq;

namespace Analyzer
{
    [Generator]
    internal class AnalyzerInit : IIncrementalGenerator
    {
        public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
            Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer();

            analyzer.Initialize(context);
        }
    }

    internal class Analyzer : IIncrementalGenerator
    {
        public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
        {
            var rules = context.SyntaxProvider
               .CreateSyntaxProvider(
                   predicate: static (s, _) => IsSyntaxTargetForGeneration(s),
                   transform: static (ctx, _) => GetSemanticTargetForGeneration(ctx))
               .Where(static m => m is not null);

            var compilation = context.CompilationProvider.Combine(rules.Collect());

            context.RegisterSourceOutput(compilation, static (spc, source) => Execute(source.Left, source.Right, spc));
        }

        private static bool IsSyntaxTargetForGeneration(SyntaxNode node)
        {
            return node is EnumDeclarationSyntax e && e.Parent is LiteralExpressionSyntax l; //This might have to be specified and i cant remember if it would be called an EnumDeclarationSyntax
        }

        private static EnumDeclarationSyntax GetSemanticTargetForGeneration(GeneratorSyntaxContext context)
        {
            var compilationUnitSyntax = (EnumDeclarationSyntax)context.Node;
    
            return compilationUnitSyntax;
        }

        public static void Execute(Compilation compilation, ImmutableArray<EnumDeclarationSyntax> enums, SourceProductionContext context)
        {
            foreach (var enumDeclaration in enums)
            {
                var semanticModel = compilation.GetSemanticModel(enumDeclaration.SyntaxTree);

                var sourceSymbol = (INamedTypeSymbol)semanticModel.GetTypeInfo(enumDeclaration).Type;
                if (sourceSymbol.MetadataName == "AppEnvironment")
                {
                    context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(new DiagnosticDescriptor("ErrorCode", "/*Title*/AppEnvironment was refered to from Literaltring", $"/*Message*/You are not allowed to do this", "/*Category*/NotAllowedCategory", DiagnosticSeverity.Error, true), enumDeclaration.GetLocation()));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Add this code to a class in a new project.
When you have created the project you can reference it from the projects that would need this to be checked.
On build the diagnostic will be reported as a build error.
Didn't test it, but as i remember, something like that would work.
Afterwards you can add whatever exceptions you want to the rule.
PS: I know there is some tool or extension to visual studio you can install and/or use to see what the different syntax nodes would be called in realtime, but i cant remember what its called. Try searching for Roslyn tutorials on YouTube.

I guess you don't want to use constants because you want strongly typed parameters and intellisense with possible value suggestions. Am I right? If so, you could use the enum-like type instead of enum. For example:
public abstract class StringEnum
{
    protected StringEnum(string value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Value { get; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}

Then define your "enum" like this:
public sealed class AppEnvironment : StringEnum
{
    public AppEnvironment(string value)
        : base(value)
    {
    }

    public static AppEnvironment Dev { get; } = new("dev");

    public static AppEnvironment Staging { get; } = new("stage");

    public static AppEnvironment Production { get; } = new("prod");
}

The ToString() is overrided to return the Value property in contrast to name in regular enum.
Of course, you need to implement IComparable<StringEnum> and IComparable, override equality operators, GetHashCode, and Equals methods.
